# Python os.walk Make It Support Unicode/UTF-8?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have researched about this issue, It seems Python 2.7 default use is ASCII, I cant switch to python 3 (default Unicode) because of libraries

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print u'порядке'`

seems to print fine it will be `??????` without `u`
but:
`print list(os.walk(ur'c:\somefoler'))` returns `\u0438\u0442...` why not readable as first print? Also I use os.walk with variables I can't use it with `ur` I'm just trying to understand how could I make my following code work with any folders/files language I use os.walk + save to file both seems not to work always `????` where Cyrillic

```
def findit(self,root, exclude_files=[], exclude_dirs=[]):
    exclude_files = (fnmatch.translate(i) for i in exclude_files)
    exclude_files = '('+')|('.join(exclude_files)+')'
    exclude_files = re.compile(exclude_files)
    exclude_dirs = (os.path.normpath(i) for i in exclude_dirs)
    exclude_dirs = (os.path.normcase(i) for i in exclude_dirs)
    exclude_dirs = set(exclude_dirs)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        if os.path.normpath(os.path.normcase(root)) in exclude_dirs:
            # exclude this dir and subdirectories
            dirs[:] = []
            continue
        for f in files:
            if not exclude_files.match(os.path.normcase(f)):
                yield os.path.join(root, f)
```

`filelist = list(findit('c:\\',exclude_files = ['*.dll', '*.dat', '*.log', '*.exe'], exclude_dirs = ['c:/windows', 'c:/program files', 'c:/else']))`

When it's a variable it seems I have to use `.decode('utf-8')`? Why not unicode such as `u'var'` if it exists and why there are many times exceptions it's not possible to convert had encountered it and saw a lot of answers with such errors I'm having hard time understanding it isn't there a way to make it just work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
root = ur'c:\somefoler'
for current,dirs,files in os.walk(root):
    for file in files:
        print file, repr(file)
```

you should see the proper thing(along side the repr that is used in the list) ... the problem is that when you print a list it prints a `repr` of its items

Comment: this will work, But as you can see I have `os.walk(root)` can't do `urroot` the alternative what I was able to find is `.decode('utf-8')` (need to double check root is unicode before?) but it doesn't seems to be reliable to work on all scenarios as far as I saw in different answers so I just can't understand how this should be done right

Comment: ah yeah I can change it on `list(findit('c:\\'` `ur` will always work? how about the file's this is only dirs files I cannot change it as easy as this

Comment: os.walk has also sub dirs, and files i also need to unicode them with `ur` some how yes I can follow your suggestion and change root with `ur` but sub categories and files will still be ASCII encoded not unicode

Comment: If I use a unicode string for the root I get `<type 'unicode'>` for the files.