# Python 2.7 - Comparing Lists with Non-ascii Characters

Tags: python, list, utf-8

I'm trying to compare list a (umlauts) and b (file_paths).  List a is a list of umlauts.  List b is a list of file paths.  I need to see which file paths in list b have any umlauts in them.  I understand the basic python syntax for comparing lists, but the umlauts are causing major headaches -- nothing I've tried (encode(), decode(), etc.) on the paths in list b is working for me.  Can anyone provide any insight on this?  Any feedback is of course greatly appreciated.  See below for my code thus far.  If I add a for loop as seen at the end, it will print the umlauts correctly to the console, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

def GetFilepaths(directory):
    file_paths = []

    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)
    return file_paths

umlauts = [u'Ä', u'Ü', u'Ö', u'ä', u'ö', u'ü']
filePathsList = GetFilepaths(r'C:\Scripts\Replace Characters\Umlauts')

for filepath in filePathsList:
    print filepath
```

Comment: Use unicode for the directory name passed to `os.walk`, i.e. `ur'C:\Scripts\Replace Characters\Umlauts'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python os.walk Make It Support Unicode/UTF-8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254063/python-os-walk-make-it-support-unicode-utf-8)

Comment: can't do `ur'C:\Scripts\Replace Characters\Umlauts` but `u'C:\\Scripts\\Replace Characters\\Umlauts'` does work -- thanks for the tip!